# Properly defining namespaces with anonymous functions

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm a bit confused with C++ namespaces, and how you define them. I have two files: `Lua.h` and `Main.cpp`. `Lua.h` contains the following helpers for running Lua scripts in a namespace:

```
#ifndef Lua_h
#define Lua_h

#include <lua.hpp>

namespace fabric
{
  namespace lua
  {
    void loadLibs(lua_State * L)
    {
      static const luaL_Reg luaLibs[] =
      {
        { "io", luaopen_io },
        { "base", luaopen_base },
        { NULL, NULL }
      };

      const luaL_Reg * lib = luaLibs;
      for (; lib->func != NULL; lib++)
      {
        lib->func(L);
        lua_settop(L, 0);
      }
    }

    void init(lua_State * L) 
    {
      loadLibs(L);
      luaL_dofile(L, "Init.lua");

      lua_close(L);
    }
  }
}

#endif
```

My `Main.cpp` files tries to run a Lua script using these helper functions:

```
#include "Lua.h"

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  fabric::lua::init();
  return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile `Main.cpp`, I get this:

```
Source/Main.cpp:9:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fabric'
  fabric::lua::init();
  ^
```

I'm just confused on how to define this namespace. The code for the helper functions is all good, but `Main.cpp` can't find the namespace. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to define this namespace correctly in C++?

**EDIT**:

Works now. For some reason my `-I` flag wasn't working on compile since I had my headers under `Include/`. I also renamed `Lua.h` to `LuaHelpers.h`.

Comment: Your code compiles for me without problems(except missed argument for `init` function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there's a conflict between your Lua.h and Lua's Lua.h. Consider renaming your file to fabric.h or something like that.

That said, putting non-inline functions into a header file will cause linker errors when the file is included into two translation units. Consider splitting the code into the typical header/implementation pair.

Comment: Are you sure? Looks like Lua's is .hpp, and the double quotation marks shouldn't search where angle brackets do until last.

Comment: @chris `lua.h` exists too. Don't know if the quotes would cause a conflict though...

Comment: @beakr, Oh, I don't use it. I just saw the hpp in your post. The quotations should look for user headers first, then system headers. All the standard says is that <> can look however it wants, and that "" can look however it wants, but if not found, must try it like it was <>.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is, the Lua library has also the file, plus you are working on Windows, so the file system is case insensitive?

*lua.hpp*

```
// lua.hpp
// Lua header files for C++
// <<extern "C">> not supplied automatically because Lua also compiles as C++

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

Comment: Mac, never Windows. but I should probably rename `Lua.h`.